# How important is AACSB accreditation for further study after an MBA?

Tags: graduate-admissions, business-school

I have read that many Doctor of Business Administration or PhD in Business Administration programs in the US tend to reject students who did not complete a master's program at an AACSB-accredited school. From checking the list, there are no AACSB programs in the country where I live and it seems that many other foreign students would similarly lack such opportunities.

- Is this true only for American students or also of international students?
- If I complete a non-AACSB-accredited program, how might this limit my opportunities for further study?
- How could I demonstrate that a foreign program has sufficient quality?

Comment: This question is in reality 4 questions all of which would be excellent individual questions that would be a lot less localized and likely receive a lot more attention.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to find out how important AACSB accreditation is is to ask some PhD in Business Administration programs. I doubt it is a hard and fast rule since most PhD programs do not need to maintain professional accreditation. I would be more worried about DBA programs since they may need to maintain AACSB accreditation.